# I have some confusion in this question as two diodes and one resistance are parallel. Can anyone help?

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

[image]

I don't understand the concept of having two different parallel diodes.

Comment: Looks like one diode is silicon and the other germanium?  If so, what do you know about the forward drops of the respective types of diode?

Comment: The two diodes are somewhat different, and you need to understand the difference between them before proceeding. In addition, your instructor may have a preferred way for you to model these diodes for your class. As always, the best strategy is to ask the instructor for help.

Comment: I think your confusion comes from wondering why anyone would want to design a circuit that way. No one would. It's just a test/homework "what if" problem.

Comment: any questions?/

Answer (score 2):

The Germanium diode has a lower threshold with a point contact into the crystal Germanium made for detecting very low RF signals and not conducting high current.  Now Schottky diodes are used for lower voltage conduction for >1mA instead of Germanium, but you can still buy the [1N34](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/42335/SEMTECH/1N34.html) from Semtech and others for whatever RF purpose.
As I recall, the 1N54 diode at 1uA is about 100 mV
[image]

So at low voltages like 100mV it will be conducting and you can apply the Shockley equations for Ge and Si diodes, but in reality unless you know the part saturation current and resulting bulk Rs of the part, the schematic is unanswerable.  The bulk resistance Rs is inversely related to the size of the semi. chip's and it's power rating and the **Ge 1N34 was never made for power, so in this circuit it doesn't do much at all.**

With 2 diode drops of 0.7V, we expect (10-1.4V)/10 to be about 8.6mA. I presume you have been taught the diode V-I equation.  The caveat not included is the power rating in this equation, which affects the electrode surface and bulk resistance of the semiconductor.

A small signal Si diode rated for 100mA will give a different result than a 1A diode above 1 mA due to the difference in bulk resistance. This is because the incremental resistance starts at very high values at threshold and when this exponential resistance drops below the fixed bulk resistance of the electrode-semi interface it becomes a fixed resistor. That works for a short pulse but as the temperature increases like a thermometer, the diode junction drops with temperature rise about -2.1mV/'C according to its thermal **r**esistance from **j**unction to **a**mbient called **Rja** given in all spec. sheets.

Ge diodes have a lower threshold, like Schottky diodes around 0.2V at about 10% of it's rated current (Est.)  but Ge and Sch diodes also have a higher bulk resistance for the same chip size., **so at some higher current and applied voltage here both (Ge, Si) diodes share equal current.**

e.g., at rated current a 1N400x series is 1 Ohm and the 1N4448/1N4148 is 10 Ohms  . If you learn the relationship between thermal dissipation of a part and diodes bulk resistance, as I have, you will find Rs=0.5/Pmax +/-50% due to design variations covers most of all diodes including LED's but not high voltage Zeners where knee R is higher than even most LED's. due to the chip size.

Again, this question is unanswerable precisely without specs for Ge and Si diodes, but it ought to trigger more questions from you.  Imagine a small resistor in series with the ideal diode equation when you use them.  The same is true for transistor switches.

Basically for *small signal Ge and Si diodes* **you think that the Ge diode will clamp the voltage 1st and the Si will not conduct, but at 8mA you will be surprised at the answer unless you have big power diodes.**  GE diodes for power are obsolete, but used in some cases for RF for low pF.

Comment: a very interesting answer - and possibly beyond that the problem setter intended :-) - but maybe not. Comment only: If this is an assignment, as it appears to be, then an initial more guiding approach may be useful. Not just sending them elsewhere to look, but perhaps engaging with them over what they expect, and why, and then whether that addresses all the issues.

Comment: Sometimes yes the Socratic Approach is better, this  time too slow and many things would be overlooked, TY @RussellMcMahon some things even Prof's don't know

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking the that the simple key (the question is looking for) is one parallel device will turn on at a lower threshold (~0.3) and the other will not fully turn on (~0.7) because it will be clamped to the smaller threshold. Notice that's not the case for the series device (it has no such limit). Everything can be worked out with that working assumption.

Comment: except the Ge diode series resistance was  so high that they are obsolete so the clamp was too weak to use as a clamp and the Si diode draws more current here. I'd like to see datasheet to backup your opinion

Comment: No. I don't disagree with your comment at all. It was very informative. I just think it's a much simpler academic problem to cover the general concept.

Comment: even academically it would be false to assume Ge and Si typical diodes have a similar VI slope.  It looks like it was taken out of another time zone like 60 years ago. it's a better question if it compared a Schottky power diode and a Si power diode.  My answer would still be relevant with the differences in Rs being higher for Sch.

Comment: -1 for false assumptions for ON resistance even though some believe this is logical for training.

Comment: Tony S’s answer is correct – you can’t possibly get an accurate answer without full datasheets and germaniums won’t behave “as expected” at currents near 10mA. But I agree with Pat that the professor couldn’t possibly have expected you to dive that deep and probably expected students to use a “rule of thumb” that “germaniums drop 0.3V and silicons drop 0.7V” or somesuch. This would be much closer to the truth if the resistors were more like 10K so the currents would be down <1mA where the germanium might better follow that rule.

Comment: I might agree if it were pre-70's, but any Prof after that dares compare Ge and Si in parallel (not Ge/Si)  deserves to be corrected in class.  I can show you that even at 10k, it is Not as you expect.  These Ge diodes were gold plated low noise diodes made for < 10uA current levels